# i need suggestions for a suitable marker clustering algorithm (highcharts/highmaps)?

Tags: highcharts

`tell me if anyone has the simplest common example of a marker clustering algorithm on a map similar to this one -` [demo](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_create/). The algorithms described in the documentation (optimizedKmeans, kmeans and grid) and also in the [example1](https://jsfiddle.net/j41fLdpn/1/) and [example2](https://jsfiddle.net/j41fLdpn/2/) are not suitable here, because with a large number of markers, grouping into clusters occurs in a strange way, magically. I need a simple regular clustering as in my [demo](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_create/)

optimizedKmeans, kmeans and grid - tried, example is given above`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure which algorithm yandex uses, however `optimizedKmeans` or `kmeans` seem quite similar when zooming in and out using buttons. The difference is when mouse zooming, which you can customize by adjusting the `mapNavigation.mouseWheelSensitivity` setting.

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rtz8u75j/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/mapNavigation.mouseWheelSensitivity

Comment: I agree, looks like kmeans/optimizedKmeans. Thank you very much for your help